# Background Service ruining Web API performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm currently developing a Web API used by our mobile application. If an API-call is made that needs to send an email, the email is added to a queue in Azure Storage. For handling the queue (reading the queue mails and actually sending them) I thought the best solution would be creating a Hosted Service that will do this in the background.

For implementing this I followed the instructions from the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I created a class that implements the abstract BackgroundService-class from .NET Core 2.1 for this. It looks like this:

```
namespace Api.BackgroundServices
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Mail queue service.
    /// This handles the queued mails one by one.
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService" />
    public class MailQueueService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MailQueueService"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceScopeFactory">The service scope factory.</param>
        public MailQueueService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
        {
            this.serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when the <see cref="T:Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService" /> starts. The implementation should return a task that represents
        /// the lifetime of the long running operation(s) being performed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stoppingToken">Triggered when <see cref="M:Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService.StopAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)" /> is called.</param>
        /// <returns>A <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task" /> that represents the long running operations.</returns>
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await HandleMailQueueAsync();
                //await Task.Delay(3000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }

        private async Task HandleMailQueueAsync()
        {
            using (IServiceScope serviceScope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                TelemetryClient telemetryClient = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<TelemetryClient>();

                try
                {
                    IMailHandler mailHandler = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMailHandler>();
                    await mailHandler.HandleMailQueueAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    telemetryClient.TrackException(exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After registering it by calling

```
services.AddHostedService<MailQueueService>();
```

in the Startup.cs, it will successfully handle the mail queue, but all other calls to the WebAPI take almost ten times as long. Only if I comment out the Task.Delay() part in my implementation of the  BackgroundService, the performance goes back to an acceptable level.

However this seems more like a workaround than a real solution for my problem. Am I doing something else wrong that makes the performance tank like this?

Comment: This is actually what you should do. The background-task, in the way you are using it now, is completely blocking the the main-process because it starts as soon as the webhost was built.

By adding `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), stoppingToken);` you should have a normal request performance. If that is still not the case, it must be something that is being used in `HandleMailQueueAsync()`.

Comment: If you really have that many mails to send, you should extract it in its own executable and run it on a different app service or background process. If its only high on peaks, azure functions may be an option. Otherwise use docker/swarm/k8s to balance it across multiple machines to spread the load and run more than 1 container if the load is really high

Comment: Hi, did you manage to figure out what was wrong with this? I have an exact same problem.

Comment: @tonycdp I didn't solve this exact problem, but I started using Hangfire for background tasks: https://www.hangfire.io/